# Power BI filter out data based on previous business day

Tags: powerbi

I have a column ReceiptDateTime which has the Date and time of receipt received. I would like to filter and use only the data which is there for the previous business day (Monday to Friday). For eg on Monday I would like to see only Friday's data. I am trying to achieve this in power BI.

Is this possible? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: It is possible. Please show what you tried?

Comment: I was trying to add a filter in the query itself but couldnot figure out.Would you suggest calculated fields instead?

Comment: create a calculated column `isyesterday` which determines if the date value of the row is previous business day, returns `1` if yes and `0` otherwise. Then you can filter by `isyesterday = 1`. (You will need functions: [today](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634554.aspx), [dateadd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee634905.aspx) and [weekday](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634550.aspx))

Comment: If the query starts getting long, make sure to use newlines (shift+enter) and variables: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/variables-in-dax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I start with this table loaded into Power BI as Table1:

[image]

I then add a new column (Modeling -> New Column) with this code...`ReceiptDateOnly = DATE(YEAR([ReceiptDateTime]),MONTH([ReceiptDateTime]),DAY([ReceiptDateTime]))`...to get *only* the date from the ReceiptDateTime column. *(You had indicated you had date/time combinations, and we'll need just the dates for what I'll do here.)*

[image]

I then create a new table (Modeling -> New Table) with this code...`Table2 = GROUPBY(Table1,Table1[ReceiptDateOnly],"SomeData",sumx(CURRENTGROUP(),Table1[SomeData])).

Then I add a new column with this code...

`PreviousWorkday = if(WEEKDAY('Table2'[Table1_ReceiptDateOnly])=2, DATEADD('Table2'[Table1_ReceiptDateOnly],-3,DAY),
    if(WEEKDAY('Table2'[Table1_ReceiptDateOnly])=1, DATEADD('Table2'[Table1_ReceiptDateOnly],-2,DAY),
        DATEADD('Table2'[Table1_ReceiptDateOnly],-1,DAY))
  )`

...to determine the previous workday.

Then I add another column with this code...

`PreviousWorkDaySomeData = SUMX(FILTER('Table2','Table2'[Table1_ReceiptDateOnly]=EARLIER('Table2'[PreviousWorkday])),'Table2'[SomeData])`

...to get the data related to the previous workday.

I get a table like this:

[image]

Monday uses Friday's data. Tuesday uses Monday's data. Wednesday uses Tuesday's data. Thursday uses Wednesday's data. Friday uses Thursday's data. Saturday uses Friday's data. Sunday uses Friday's data.